# Android Proguard Classes Obfuscation

Tags: android-proguard

I am enabling proguard to obfuscate my app's code. I have set `minifyEnabled` to true inside `build.gradle` and added `-printconfiguration "build/outputs/mapping/configuration.txt"` to my `proguard-rules.pro` but it doesn't obfuscate class names?

Why it doesn't obfuscate them?
I also want to hide: logs,names of directories(i.e. `/sys/bus/usb/devices`) and inside classes to hide extends Service and extends `BroadcastReceiver`?